# Why can't I return the first element of an array in a template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> T getArray( T &arr ) {
    return *arr;
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {5, 3, 6};

    std::cout << getArray(a);

}
```

It's suppose to print the first element in the array but it is not not working. Why is that?

It gives me the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'getArray(int [3])'
```

Comment: "it is not not working" - can you elaborate?

Comment: Post it again and show your expected and actual output and tell us why you're confused :)

Comment: The type of `a` is `int[3]`, so the type of `T` is `int[3]`. Arrays cannot be returned from functions.

Comment: i think that you should read about the difference between C and C++ regarding the pointers.

Comment: You should get a compiler error because arrays are passed to functions as pointers, not references.  IOW, `getArray` should take a `T*`, not a `T&`.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: While the question is not really well written out, I do think that it is an interesting question, as it is pure SFINAE where you would not expect it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It was definitely NARC question before the first edit. (which was made within the first 5 min. so you can't see it)

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Arrays can be passed by reference, what you cannot do is pass by value. `void f( int *array )` -- decay, the array is not passed in, but a pointer to the first element. `void f( int (*array)[3] )` -- array passed by pointer, `void f( int (&array)[3] )` array passed by reference.

Comment: @Mysticial: I have not seen any previous version of the question... Still closing without giving a chance to edit the question seems harsh

Comment: If, instead of `template <typename T> T getArray( T &arr )`, you were to write `typedef` __XYZ__ `T;` followed by a valid function prototype for `getArray` in terms of T, what would you write in place of __XYZ__?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'll accept that correction.  I was a little sloppy in my comment.  My point wasn't that arrays *can't* be passed by reference, but that when you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer unless you do extra work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of `a` is `int[3]`, so the type of `T` is `int[3]`. **Arrays cannot be returned from functions.**

In C++11, you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
auto getArray(T &arr) -> decltype(*arr)
{ 
    return *arr; 
}
```

Or this:

```
// requires <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::remove_extent<T>::type& getArray(T &arr)
{ 
    return *arr; 
}
```

In C++03 you can do this, but it's not quite the same:

```
template <typename T>
T getArray(T* arr /* not really an array */)
{ 
    return *arr; 
}
```

Or:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T getArray(T (&arr)[N])
{ 
    return *arr; 
}
```

Comment: In case the OP is wondering how `remove_extent` may be defined: `template<class T> struct remove_extent { typedef typename T type; };
template<class T, size_t N> struct remove_extent<T[N]> { typedef typename T type; };`

Comment: It seems to me that this results in two functionally different function templates, because the one using decltype will return a reference, and the one using remove_extent returns by value.

Comment: I'm a beginner. I get that these functions are supposed to return the first element in the array, but what I don't get is what `-> decltype(*arr)` and `size_t` is suppose to do?

Comment: @user6607: `decltype` gives you the type of an expression. Because `*arr` has the type `int&`, the function returns an `int&`. We let the compiler do the work of figuring out what to return. `size_t` is an unsigned integer type that's used for holding the size of things, including arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T getArray( T (&arr)[N] ) {
    return *arr;
}
```

so that `T` is the type of the element, not the array.

Answer (score 1):

It does not even compile on MSVC++ 2010 Express. As I expected, this is because you are using a reference as a parameter, a scalar as a return value and a pointer is passed to the function call. I do not know the exact rules regarding templates (i.e. how exactly the type is determined) but that code has to be confusing the hell out of the compiler. The following code returns what you expected it to return.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> T getArray( T* arr ) {
    return *arr;
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {5, 3, 6};

    std::cout << getArray(a);

}
```

Comment: In the original code, there is no pointer being passed to the function, rather a reference to an array. Since that makes `T` be an array and an array cannot be returned SFINAE is disabling that template. It is important not to confuse people with the bad-old *an array is a pointer* thing.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try :

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> T getArray( T arr[] ) {
    return *arr;
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {5, 3, 6};

    std::cout << getArray(a);

}
```

Comment: to be conform to last standards you should change `iostream.h` to `iostream` and add the line `using namespace std;` or use `std::cout`. I didn't that on my response in other to follow you code style.